# ASP Button (Command vs Submit)

Tags: asp.net, html, submit, form-submit, forms

I want this to be a command button not a submit button, so that when the user presses  the "Submit" button is "clicked".

```
ASP Code:
<asp:Button CommandName="StartButtonName" CommandArgument="soo"
     CausesValidation="false" ID="StartButton" Text="..."
     Visible="false" runat="server" OnClick="StartButton_Click" />

Generated HTML code
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$StartButton"
       value="..." id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_StartButton" />
```

Why does my ASP Code not generate a command button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `UseSubmitBehavior` to `false`. See [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx) for more info.